# how to connect and insert and retrieve data from database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","music123_sri","password");
 if (!$con) 
  { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } 
mysql_select_db("music123_telugu", $con);
 $sql="INSERT INTO xml (File) VALUES (" . mysql_escape_string($xmlString) . ")"; 

$data = mysql_query("SELECT File FROM xml")

 $info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
```

can u help me in coding for connecting to database and inserting data and retrieving data

Comment: its not connecting to database i think.
mysql_query($sql);
i added thi line after $sql=...........

Comment: If it doesn't connect, it should give an error message. Please post more info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in some other answer to one of your questions: please read some introduction on how to use PHP with MySQL. A lot of problems will disappear when you get some sort of understanding on how these pieces fit together.

In your concrete example you have three problems:

1. Your `INSERT`-query is never executed as it's never send to the database server
2. You only retrieve the first row from the result set of your query using `mysql_fetch_array()`
3. There is a ; missing - so your code is not even valid PHP

I won't give you a finished code snippet but some advice: carefully read the PHP manual for [`mysql_query()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) and try to understand how they fit into your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a semi-colon after `$data = mysql_query("SELECT File FROM xml")`.